# AMQP binding and message removing

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

How to remove message from a queue , in a bining configuration, once the message has been consumed?

Example:

I have

topic.1, topic.2, topic.3,...etc

I have two binding, like my_topic which is binded to topic.1 and all_topic which is binded to topic.#

my_topic is high priority, and messages are consumed normally, but remains in the topic.# binding. So how can I remove them from the topic.# so they are not consumed twice?

Thanks in advance

Comment: the two bindings are for the same queue or different ones.  Are you using auto ack? normally messages are removed from the queue after they are read.  Do you have more than one consumer connecting to the queue?

Comment: the two bindings are for the same queue, with more than one consumer connecting to the queue. The scenario is to have the ability to consume some messages in priority if needed. For the auto ack, I did not set anything, so I guess it's the default? The message are removed from the queue once read, but for EACH binding!

Comment: I think the auto ack is default, I think though you have problem with your design. Off the top of my head I don't think you receive two messages because you have two bindings that fits one routing key.  Also the only reason you should have two consumers connected to one queue is for a work queue set up. Where you each consumer reads different messages.  Rephrase your question by what you want to achieve, ie your goals and not your expectations from what you have done, and I will do what I can to help you.

Comment: ok,here is the design:

- I have one producer and several consumers
- Most of the time,everything works in real time, but some occasions, consumers does not consume fast enough and the queue is growing
- in that case, I want to be able to consume some message in priority , depending of the topic (exemple: instead of having 5 worked on all topics, I want 3 worked on topic 1, and 2 others on others topics)

Comment: pretty sure you cannot do that with one queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split your topics in more queues. So instead of having one queue subscribed to messages with routing key "users.*", create one for each routing key: "users.created", "users.updated", "users.deleted". Then you can create new consumers to bind to this queue on the fly when you have more load in one kind of message.

Comment: the problemwithmore queue is that I wanted to do something generic without nowing the queue names, except on the one I wanted to "raise up", but I'll do like this...